# need some enlightenment on the behaviour of the React code

Tags: reactjs

I have this set of code and basically what I am trying to achieve is the selected option when on the edit page.

```
//this one works
const [artData, setArtData] = useState([])
const [catID, setCatID] = useState('')
const [catTitle, setCatTitle] = useState('')
    
setTutorialData(response.data.art)
setCatID(response.data.art.category._id)
setCatTitle(response.data.art.category.title)  
  

    <select
      id="categoryid"
      className="form-control"
      name="category"
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
        {categoryData.map(option => (
             <option value={option._id} >{option.title}</option>
        ))}
        **<option selected value={catID}>{catTitle}</option>**
    </select>
```

But for this one, it complained that TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

```
    <select
      id="categoryid"
      className="form-control"
      name="category"
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
        {categoryData.map(option => (
             <option value={option._id} >{option.title}</option>
        ))}
        **<option selected value={artData.category._id}>
            {artData.category.title}
          </option>**
    </select>
```

Why does this happen? When I did a console.log, it printed the values.

```
  const response = await Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + `/api/art/editart/${id}`, {withCredentials:true})
        setArtData(response.data.art)
        console.log(response.data.art.category._id) //5fedeec19604432ac034bf89

        console.log(response.data.art.category.title) //ReactJS
```

Comment: `artData` is an array, so `artData.category` should be undefined, and then throw an error when you attempt to access `_id` of undefined. The console log should fail equally. Perhaps something is mutating your state object and it becomes valid by the time your console log is interacted with in your browser. Can you provide a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of the code you are running, with the reproduction steps for error?

Comment: @Drew Reese, You are right, the console log would fail equally. I posted the wrong console log code. It should have been this   const response = await Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + `/api/art/editart/${id}`, {withCredentials:true})
        setArtData(response.data.tutorial)
        console.log(response.data.art.category._id)
        console.log(response.data.art.category.title). The console log did print the value. Thanks

Comment: Can you post that code in your question, and also include what the response object output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your `artData` state object shape doesn't match what your GET request returns and you store in state.

From

```
const response = await Axios.get(
  process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + `/api/art/editart/${id}`,
  { withCredentials: true },
);
setArtData(response.data.art);
console.log(response.data.art.category._id) //5fedeec19604432ac034bf89
console.log(response.data.art.category.title) //ReactJS
```

It seems your response is an object, but you've defined your initial `artData` state to be an array.

```
const [artData, setArtData] = useState([]);
```

So on the initial render before the data is fetched `artData.category` will be undefined and throw error if you attempt to access further into the undefined object.

## Solution

Provide better initial state so error won't be thrown.

```
const [artData, setArtData] = useState({
  category: {},
});
```

This way `artData.category` is defined and attempting `artData.category.id` will just be undefined and not throw an error.

Alternatively you could stick with the version where you've split out the `id` and `title` into their own state.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
 {categoryData?.map(option => (
         <option value={option._id} >{option.title}</option>
    ))}
<option selected value={artData?.category?._id}>
        {artData?.category?.title}
      </option>
```

Comment: hi Ahmed, this is the first time I see a question mark. What does it mean? Thanks

Comment: @Nat The `?.` is the [Optional Chaining Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) that allows succinct null checks so you don't access properties of undefined objects. It's very useful but in this case is more of a band-aid and doesn't address the cause as to why the value/object was undefined.

Comment: well, this called optional chaining operator, same as  artData ? artData : undefined  . but this one is shorthand to grab properties in hirarchy way. for example, here in ur code {categoryData?.map()  categoryData?.map means categoryData?categoryData.map(): undefined so it does two things, check if the value exists, in case it does your code otherwise it handles the falsy case for you

Comment: thanks a lot and I learned a lot today. Thanks again, Reese and Ahmed.